# Reconocimiento de color en una sección específica de la cámara

Tags: python

Desarrollé un programa para la detección de colores (blanco, rojo, azul, amarillo) a través de la webcam, que funciona bien, sin problemas. Pero lo que me gustaría saber ahora es si puedo hacer que los colores no se detecten en toda la cámara sino en una sección específica. Como muestro en la imagen, quiero que la detección de los colores ocurra dentro del recuadro marrón y no en toda la cámara.

[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Dejo la porción de código donde defino el cuadro marrón y la forma en que detecto el color blanco.

```
rec = cv2.rectangle(img, (600, 350), (10 + 51, 200 + 51), (93, 109, 126), 2)

    # Tracking white
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(white, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for pic, contour in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
    if(area > 300):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, "BLANCO: ", (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1.0, (255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: Acaso no haría falta verificar si el color a detectar se encuentra en el área del rectángulo marrón?

Comment: Yo quiero que solo detecte dentro del rectangulo marron. lo que no se es que debo modificar para lograr esto, las modificaciones que hice me dan error